# if my javascript front-end pulls in an unmodified version of a GPLv3 library, must I release the whole source code for the website?

Tags: gpl-3

I want to use a javascript library licensed under the GPLv3 for a new website I am building. I want my website to remain closed-source. The GitHub repository of the GPLv3 states that anyone using their library on a publicly facing website must open-source their entire website, but I believe this may be incorrect. If I pull in their library separately from the rest of my javascript bundle, so that it is distinct and clear that I am using an unmodified version, which includes their copyright text, and that isn't intermingled with my own code through some bundler software. Doesn't that then mean that I am not obliged to release the rest of my website's front-end javascript code?

Comment: This scenario probably has an equivalence to releasing code that explicitly describes a GPL'd library dependency via package manager (e.g., Python's `install_requires` in `setup.py`) without actually including any material from that library. In the space of this comment, though, I won't attempt to answer either question.

Comment: (Not a lawyer, or acting as one, but here is my understanding) As Free-Software / Open-Source definitions prohibit discrimination by use, and you are not modify the library to depend on your code, and if your code is not a thin wrapper. Then so long as you comply with the libraries licence (GPL is in compliance with the Free-Software definition). Then you should be OK. This all supposes, that it is considered that the GPL-v3 is the licence, and not the other words that prohibit your actions. However why are you writing proprietary software?

Comment: Did you read the GPLv3?

Comment: AFAIK (and I am not a lawyer either) writing substantial code using the library generally constitutes "creating a derived work" of the library. Also, your website, if taken as a whole, *contains* the library and must therefore be distributed as GPLv3 (since it is not a "mere aggregation").